# Why use scope operator (::) before class initialization in C++?

Tags: c++, class, scope, initialization

I sometimes see before initialization class scope operator ::, why is it used there?

What is differences between for example:

> HRESULT hRes = ::CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);

and

> HRESULT hRes = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);

Comment: It explicitly designates the global namespace. If, for example, some funny/unprofessional/inexperienced pseudo-programmer pollutes one of your header files with the `abusing namespace XY;` directive, and namespace XY happens to have a function named `CoInitializeEx`, then that function will shadow the global one (the one you really intended to call).

Comment: Even without such pollution, qualification prevents ADL.

Answer (score 6):

`::` refers to the global namespace. You'd find names there anyway, so it's not often required.

However, there are 2 reasons why you'd use this. An unqualified name can potentially come from many namespaces, and there are non-trivial rules (such as Argument-dependent lookup) to determine which namespaces to search in which order. A qualified name is looked up only in the namespace given.

The second reason is that inside class member functions, unqualified names are first looked up in class scope, and again a qualified name avoids this.

Answer (score 3):

It simply means as below:

```
HRESULT hRes = ::CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
The "CoInitializeEx" function uses the global scope // Not from local scope.
```

and

```
HRESULT hRes = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
The "CoInitializeEx" function uses the local Scope.
```